# How to add multiple limits in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select **SUM** of last 200,100 and 50 rows of close price from a table in a single query.
given below is the query for 200 rows.

```
SELECT SUM(Close_price) as tot200 FROM cash_data ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 0,200
```

can anyone help me with this.

Comment: And the result should be?

Comment: @ juergen d i just edited my question please check it now. I want the result like this tot200 ,tot100 and tot50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sub queries -

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(Close_price) FROM cash_data ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 0,200) as tot200, 
(SELECT SUM(Close_price) FROM cash_data ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 0,100)  as tot100,
(SELECT SUM(Close_price) FROM cash_data ORDER BY date_added LIMIT 0,50)  as tot50
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it in a single select without any subselects you can use a ranking varaible and sum conditionally

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1, 
       SUM(case when @rank <= 50 then Close_price else 0 end) as top_50_sum, 
       SUM(case when @rank <= 100 then Close_price else 0 end) as top_100_sum,
       SUM(case when @rank <= 200 then Close_price else 0 end) as top_200_sum
FROM cash_data 
cross join (select @rank := 0) r
ORDER BY date_added 
LIMIT 0,200
```

Comment: thanks @ juergen d. i will try it and let you know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. Actually both the answers are working but i choose the second one and made some changes for my need. Below is the final query

```
SELECT 
(SELECT SUM(Close_price)/200 FROM (SELECT Close_price FROM cash_data WHERE SERIES='$series' AND SYMBOL='$symbol' AND date_added <= '$date' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,200) as tot200) as avg200, 
(SELECT SUM(Close_price)/100 FROM (SELECT Close_price FROM cash_data WHERE SERIES='$series' AND SYMBOL='$symbol' AND date_added <= '$date' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,100) as tot100) as avg100,
(SELECT SUM(Close_price)/50 FROM (SELECT Close_price FROM cash_data WHERE SERIES='$series' AND SYMBOL='$symbol' AND date_added <= '$date' ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 0,50) as tot50) as avg50
```

Thank you all.